# Join strings from consecutive equal tuples

Tags: python, list

Given a list which looks like this:

```
[(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (1, 'd')]
```

I want to join the consecutive tuples inside the list if they have same first value, so the result looks like following:

```
[(1, 'ab'), (2, 'c'), (1, 'd')]
```

Should only join if both are next to each other.

If key is None like below it should be merged to previous item.

```
[(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (None, 'e'), (2, 'c'), (1, 'd')]
```

result should be

```
[(1, 'abe'), (2, 'c'), (1, 'd')]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group consecutive sublists with the same first value,  and `join` the strings from the corresponding *gruoped* tuples:

```
from itertools import groupby
l = [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (1, 'd')]

[(k,''.join([i for _,i in v])) for k,v in groupby(l, key=lambda x:x[0])]
# [(1, 'ab'), (2, 'c'), (1, 'd')]
```

Comment: great answer. Spicing up a bit more if input contains key as None it should be merged. Like [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (None, 'e'), (2, 'c'), (None, 'f'), (1, 'd')] it should result in [(1, 'abe'), (2, 'cf'), (1, 'd')]

Comment: This leads to quite a different approach @varun , not as straight forward as grouping. Please for a different question ask a new question here in SO

Comment: This was not included in the original question. As mentioned, this is a different question, I encourage you to post a new *different* question in SO for this @varun

Comment: @varun, In the case of none, you can do a single pass on your list and replace all None values with the one before it